# Libgdx: ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap returning blank black Pixmap on Android

Tags: android, image, file-io, libgdx, screenshot

I'm trying to use libgdx to take a screenshot on android, save it to a .PNG image, and then use an Intent to offer options to share it. So far, the code runs without error messages and the Intent works fine, but the .PNG is being saved as a totally blank (black) image, although it seems to have the right dimensions at least. The .PNG file that is saved when I run the desktop project looks just fine and I managed to, through trial and error, narrow down my search for the source of this issue to the ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap() function. On Desktop, it returns a Pixmap containing my screenshot, just like I expected it to, but it returns a Pixmap that is totally blank when I run it on android. Any ideas as to what could be causing this? Here's some of the code:

```
public void share() {

         try{
                FileHandle fh;
                fh = new FileHandle(Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath() + "TrailBlazerScores" + ".png");
                System.out.println(fh);
                fh.delete();
                Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-WIDTH)/2, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
                PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
                pixmap.dispose();
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        this.actionResolver.shareScreenshot(fh.toString()); //This runs the android-specific Intent code
}

private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean yDown){
    final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);
    ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
    final int numBytes = w * h * 4;
    byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
    if (yDown) {
        // Flip the pixmap upside down
        int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
            pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
        }
        pixels.clear();
        pixels.put(lines);
    }
    pixmap.setColor(Color.RED);
    pixmap.fillCircle(0, 0, 60);
    return pixmap;
}
```

The circle I draw on the pixmap just before returning it was just for the purposes of seeing if the problem was in saving the file or in constructing the Pixmap. The file that android creates is totally black save for the red circle in the top left, so I know that PixmapIO is working correctly.

Comment: Try commenting out all the line flipping code.  (Just return the pixmap immediately.)  Also, is your renderer doing anything interesting or unusual?

Comment: @P.T. I've tried that - the Pixmap was still blank. I use scene2d and SpriteBatch's normal draw() methods to render all my stuff, so I'm pretty sure there's nothing off there.

Comment: You could try moving around when in your render loop you invoke this.  What device are you using?  (which GPU?)  Anything interesting in the Android logs?  (Your code looks fine, and similar to mine ...)

Comment: @P.T. I've tried moving it around in the render loop, but there are only so many places I can put it without calling it before all the elements have been rendered to the screen. I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy SII Skyrocket, which has an Adreno 220. I don't have enough hardware knowledge to even begin to understand if that's the problem though.

Comment: You could try checking for GLErrors?  (Be sure to check for errors before the screenshot, since they persist.)  Your device seems sane enough.  You might try playing around with the raw glReadPixels call and see if you can change the format its reading or something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have acces to libgdx atm, but if you have libgdx then you have access to lwgjl natives aswell I asume since it is packed in with libgdx.

Here is what I cooked up some times ago in lwgjl-natives.

```
 private void screenShot(){
             //Creating an rbg array of total pixels
             int[] pixels = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
             int bindex;
             // allocate space for RBG pixels
             ByteBuffer fb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3);

             // grab a copy of the current frame contents as RGB
             glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, fb);

             BufferedImage imageIn = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
             // convert RGB data in ByteBuffer to integer array
             for (int i=0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
                 bindex = i * 3;
                 pixels[i] =
                     ((fb.get(bindex) << 16))  +
                     ((fb.get(bindex+1) << 8))  +
                     ((fb.get(bindex+2) << 0));
             }
             //Allocate colored pixel to buffered Image
             imageIn.setRGB(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, pixels, 0 , WIDTH);

             //Creating the transformation direction (horizontal)
             AffineTransform at =  AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1, -1);
             at.translate(0, -imageIn.getHeight(null));

             //Applying transformation
             AffineTransformOp opRotated = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
             BufferedImage imageOut = opRotated.filter(imageIn, null);

             try {//Try to screate image, else show exception.
                 ImageIO.write(imageOut, format , fileLoc);
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println("ScreenShot() exception: " +e);
             }
         }
```